# How to find that current Blackberry device support Hindi(or Gujarathi) or not?

Tags: blackberry

Hi blackberry developers,

I am implemented one application targeted to OS6 and above.
Here i am loading url which is contain some Indian (Gujarathi) language into the browserField.
Here My problem is that text displaying some devices correctly but not all.
it is showing text properly in Bold 9780 OS6, But Tourch 9800 OS7 is not showing properly.It is showing only Rectangular Boxes.
So i need to know that is my devise support gujarathi language are not first.

I am using some code to get list of available languages

```
Locale []loc1=Locale.getAvailableInputLocales();
            for(int i=0;i<loc1.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("=====1: "+loc1[i].getLanguage()+"======"+loc1[i].getDisplayLanguage());
                RichTextField rh1=new RichTextField("ISO: "+loc1[i].getLanguage()+"==name: "+loc1[i].getDisplayLanguage(),Field.FOCUSABLE);
                add(rh1);
            }
   String []loc2=Locale.getISOLanguages();
            for(int i=0;i<loc2.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("=====2: "+loc2[i]);
                RichTextField rh2=new RichTextField("ISO: "+loc2[i],Field.FOCUSABLE);
                add(rh2);
            }
```

in both cases it is displaying as attachment.
And strange thing is that in both array's i am not finding any language named as "Gujarathi" or "gu(ISO code)". But perfectly displaying data on my 9780 but 9800 not showing.

So Here i want to know what is the reason behind this ?

1) If suppose my devise is supporting "Gujarathi" Language then why it is not showing it's name in Locale.getISOLanguages(); or Locale.getAvailableInputLocales();?

2)How can we know that current device can support  required language language?

I also tried using desktop-manager--->Applications------->available languages even here also i am not finding anything related to indian languages

I need to give answer to Client that what is the reason behind this ?

I goggled for 12Hrs. But no use So i decided that  you are my only hope?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Checking Localization Demo

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/33805/Localization_sample_app_files_1791764_11.jsp